# Freetype correct size rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype2

I'm currently writing an OpenGL application that render a lot of text. Text rendering was previously done with Qt but for performence reason we change all by OpenGL rendering.

I made all the shader / rendering pipeline, it's working well.
But after reading the doc of freetype again, I still don't understand how to render correctly at the right size.

For now I use the function

```
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, mFontSize);
```

To set the size of my font, but I know that it's incorrect, because Qt was rendering in 'point' (I guess..), so all the text is now smaller.

I read about using the function

```
FT_Set_Char_Size(
      face,    /* handle to face object           */
      0,       /* char_width in 1/64th of points  */
      16*64,   /* char_height in 1/64th of points */
      300,     /* horizontal device resolution    */
      300 );   /* vertical device resolution      */
```

And here come my first question, what I should put in the resolution? I can't know the DPI of the screen... What standard I should use?

Also, I need the text to be at fixed size on the screen, at whatever the zoom is. For now, I pre-compute my glyph's vertex on CPU side as on this tutorial https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering
But for the parameter "scale", I use 1.f / font_size.

And then, on the shader I do

```
(camera * vec3(char_position.xy, 1)).xy + vertex.xy / viewport * font_size.
```

With this I can have fixed size on the screen, with a maximum of 45 pixel as I asked to freetype. But it's not correct from the point of view of what was rendered by Qt.

But I don't see how to do it with the DPI 'solution'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't calculate an accurate DPI for your system (a claim which I'm very skeptical of; check your documentation) then you're going to need to do what most other solutions do: guess.

Windows, for example, assumes a DPI of 96 is "normal" for most systems, and if you're unable to provide an accurate number, it's probably a good number to use for your project.

So if you absolutely cannot get an accurate DPI number, just punch in 96 and then scale your font sizes from there.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer ! On "my" documentation there is no mention of DPI. I can compute it, but the reality is that we don't know on what screen it will run.
And then ? How could I be sure that I'm rendering correctly the font ?

Comment: @ErwanDaniel The Windowing API that you're using probably gives a way to retrieve the DPI for a given monitor/device. GLFW, for example, gives a way to retrieve both the resolution and physical dimensions of each monitor on the system, which together can be used by the programmer to calculate DPI. You'll need to see if the Windowing API you're using provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a project in Qt/OpenGL for unicode font rendering using freetype library. Hope this helps https://github.com/arunrvk/Qt-OpenGL-Fonts-with-Freetype-Library